# Bash script works fine when run manually through the server, but does not send the output when run via crontab

Tags: bash, cron

I have created a bash script to login as sysdba and run a specific query, then take the output to send it to Google Chat via a Webhook.

The problem is, the script runs fine when I login to the server and manually execute the script with ./script.sh .
This script should be executed everyday at a specific time, hence I have created a cronjob.
But when the cronjob runs, the query does not return any output.

Below is the code of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/oracle/DR_Sync_Status_QA/

#PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin

# File to save the SQL output
OUTPUT_FILE="/home/oracle/output.txt"

touch /home/oracle/output.txt

chmod 666 /home/oracle/output.txt

# Google Chat webhook URL
CHAT_WEBHOOK_URL="url"

# Log in to Oracle Database as SYSDBA and execute the SQL command, save the output to a file
sqlplus -S / as sysdba <<EOF > ${OUTPUT_FILE}
set linesize 500 pagesize 1000 feedback off verify off
SELECT al.thread#, MAX(al.sequence#) AS "shipped log", MAX(lh.sequence#) AS "applied log"
FROM v\$archived_log al, v\$archived_log lh
WHERE al.thread# = lh.thread#
AND AL.RESETLOGS_CHANGE# = LH.RESETLOGS_CHANGE#
AND AL.RESETLOGS_CHANGE# = (SELECT MAX(RESETLOGS_CHANGE#) FROM v\$archived_log)
AND lh.APPLIED = 'YES'
GROUP BY al.thread#
ORDER BY 1;
EOF

# Send the output to Google Chat using the webhook
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\":\"$(cat ${OUTPUT_FILE})\"}" ${CHAT_WEBHOOK_URL}

# Clean up: remove the temporary output file
#rm ${OUTPUT_FILE}

exit
```

I have tried executing the command after assigning it to a variable as well, still works when run manually but not with cron.

This is the crontab

*/2 * * * * sh /home/oracle/DR_Sync_Status_QA/DR_SYNC_QA.sh

Please note: The cronjob is setup with oracle user.

Comment: The duplicate at the very least tells you how to provide useful debugging details. "It doesn't run" could depend on at least half a dozen things, starting from simple syntax errors to not having the `cron` daemon running. Feel free to [edit] this questions with pertinent troubleshooting details and we can reopen it.